# Error in Building a URDF from Scrath

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been following the tutorial from: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch

I am currently attempting to run the 4th example 'Origins' using the command:

`roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/03-origins.urdf`

However, every time I get an error in Rviz, essentially the leg is sticking straight through the middle of the base rather than being traslated to the side. I'm in the `urdf_tutorial` directory and have installed the `joint_state_publisher` package, so these are not the issues.

I'm encountering the error 'No transform from [right_leg] to [base_link]' and 'No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [base_link] does not exist'. Any ideas on how to fix this? (If I was able to, I would upload a screenshot as well)

The urdf file I'm using is the same as from the tutorial, but posted below as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="origins">
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.6" radius="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="right_leg">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 .2 .1"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 1.57075 0" xyz="0 0 -0.3"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_to_right_leg" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_leg"/>
    <origin xyz="0.22 0 .25"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209764/error-in-building-a-urdf-from-scrath/) by [Blumouse](https://answers.ros.org/users/22521/blumouse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-05-22**:
i think you need to show your urdf file

**Comment by [Blumouse](https://answers.ros.org/users/22521/blumouse/) on 2015-05-22**:
It's an urdf file in the urdf_tutorial package, but I posted for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out. Just needing to restart roscore in the end, although It seems like too simple of a fix.

---

Originally posted by [Blumouse](https://answers.ros.org/users/22521/blumouse/) with karma: 21 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that the fixed frame in rviz is set to base_link. This should be the default when using the launch file, but I'm guessing it got changed somehow.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1